# How do I parse this object returned in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am receiving the following response, though I cannot figure out the best way to parse the data.  Can it be assigned to an array?

```
{ message_type="oauth2_complete", code="4809c705bd1453fea1e20c442c41d96e4c32c03765cb5bfc69", state="robot" }
```

You can see/run the code here:  http://jsfiddle.net/nfg9j/1/

Login information for the account is 
Email: test@mailinator.com 
Password: password1

Comment: *"I am receiving the following response"* ***From what***?

Comment: That's not any of the standard web formats. It's a *bit* like JSON, but it's not JSON. So, you *can* assign it to an array (in JavaScript, you presumably mean "object" not "array"), but you'd have to parse it first.

Comment: Yeah, it isn't JSON, so I am unfamiliar with how to parse it.

Comment: [I'm not sure this is supposed to be used with JavaScript](https://www.wepay.com/developer/resources/sdks) (aside from Node.js).

Comment: As much as I hate to suggest it, you can actually `eval` this.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: No you can't, not without editing it first. Not rationally, at least.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: `eval('{ message_type="oauth2_complete", code="4809c705bd1453fea1e20c442c41d96e4c32c03765cb5bfc69", state="robot" }'); console.log(message_type)`.  BAM! :-D

Comment: @Blazemonger: Great link!

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Oh that's a very, ***very*** bad idea. *And* it relies on *The Horror of Implicit Globals*.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Can you fiddle that for me?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Forget the result.  What I am saying is that `{}` is a code block and can be `eval`d.  I don't suggest it, but you can.

Comment: @bmorehokie: Enjoy. http://jsfiddle.net/yQDLf/

Comment: @bmorehokie: How are you making this request?  The API's gotta have a way to get valid JSON.

Comment: @bmorehokie: Again, I don't suggest it.  There's got to be a way to get valid JSON from your API.

Comment: The API indicates JSON should be returned...but it isn't. https://www.wepay.com/developer/reference/oauth2#authorize

Comment: @bmorehokie: Are you calling the API directly?  Can you show your code?  (Obviously remove your API/Secret key)

Comment: @bmorehokie: I followed that link. The characters `json` don't appear anywhere on that page.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Our exact code (minus our key and redirect url) are located on that page linked, under the OAuth2 popup example.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder look at the response object at the bottom of the page, that is JSON.

Comment: Your example works correctly.  `data` is an object, like expected.  It's not a JSON string, it's an object, it was parsed for you.

Comment: @bmorehokie: Most times when you're given code like that, the callbacks will be passed the data already parsed :)

Answer (score 0):

If the `=` where `:` (and you had double quotes around the keys) you could use `getJSON` but if you ABSOLUTELY have to parse this and there is no way of getting a **valid** response, you could turn into a string with `String(object)`, and use `split(",")` followed by `split('=')` to retrieve your key-value pairs. I've never seen this type of response tho...

Comment: I was thinking about replacing the equals signs with colons...would I then be able to treat as json?

Comment: @bmorehokie: You would also need to add double quotes around the keys.

Comment: yes @RocketHazmat is right too, this is only a work around however you would be better off requesting a valid JSON response from wepay, that is your best bet

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I noted that in my comment directly above yours. I'll edit my answer for you lol

Answer (score 0):

Considering that it is not a standard format, you could use a regular expression to parse the text response:

```
var responseText='{ message_type="oauth2_complete", code="4809c705bd1453fea1e20c442c41d96e4c32c03765cb5bfc69", state="robot" }';
var parsedResponse={};
responseText.replace(/(\w+?)="([^"]*)"/g,function($0,$1,$2){parsedResponse[$1]=$2;});
console.log(parsedResponse);
```

$1 captures the key, $2 captures the value.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/G6TSd/